# Which startup applications can I safely turn off?

Tags: startup

I see:

- Bluetooth manager
- Certificate and key storage
- check for new hardware drivers
- disk notifications
- GNOME login sound
- GSettings Data Conversion
- Network Manager
- NVDIA X Server Settings
- Power Manager
- Print Queue Applet
- PulseAudio Sound System
- PulseAudio Sound System KDE Routing Policy
- Remote Desktop
- Secret Storage Service
- SSH Key Agent
- Ubuntu One
- Update Notifier
- User folders update
- Visual Assistance

I'd like to turn off these:

- Bluetooth manager
- disk notifications
- GNOME login sound
- GSettings Data Conversion
- Power Manager
- Remote Desktop
- Ubuntu One
- User folders update
- Visual Assistance

Comment: That depends on what you use and what you might maybe use in the future...

Comment: I guess with some of these its more obvious what I loose if I turn them off.  I imagine if I turn off "Bluetooth manager" I will lose Bluetooth, I am ok with that.  What do I lose if I turn off "GSettings Data Conversion"?

Comment: I just think these all doesnt need to be loaded on the startup, we could just load them a bit later when the cpu is more free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Bluetooth manager: bluetooth won't work until you re-enable it and re-login
- disk notifications: don't disable it, it will warn you if your disk is going to die soon!
- login sound: safe to disable
- GSettings data conversion: I would leave this turned on, as it might cause problems in the future otherwise
- power manager: you better keep this running
- remote desktop: might be okay if you don't use it
- Ubuntu One: again, if you don't use it...
- User folder update: might be useful to keep it in case of changes in the future
- visual assistance: if you are 100% sure nobody will ever need accessibility tools on this system...

Answer (score 2):

I'd leave `GSettings Data Conversion`, `Disk Notifications` and `Power Manager` alone.

*Please imagine a sidenote about "how this most likely won't effect the overall performance" here. Thank you.*